# Call js function on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a js file where there is a function with multiple parameters

```
function initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, CLONES_COUNT, doAutoPlay) {
. . .
}
```

And I want to use this function on different pages, but with slightly different parameters, let's say for one of the pages there will be

```
initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1)
```

I tried like this

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
   });
</script>
@endsection
```

I seem to be doing everything right, but I get errors

> jQuery.Deferred exception: initSlider is not defined ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined at HTMLDocument. (http://test.loc/blog/article_1:730:9)
> at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:30038)
> at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:30340) undefined

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined at HTMLDocument. (article_1:730)
> at e (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
> at t (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

Comment: create a script file and you could export/import it

Comment: @HossamMaher no difference at all, the same error